# App does not close after calling finish() in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments, android-alertdialog

I am working on an app in which I have one dialog and when I click on the exit button I want to close the app but sometimes app won't finish and return back to my first activity. I do not understand what to do with this.

**Code for the same**

```
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
        alertDialog.setMessage(context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_close_dialog_msg));
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.app_close_dialog_msg_yes, new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dismiss();
                ((Activity) context).finish();
                //((Activity) context). moveTaskToBack(true);
                System.exit(0);
                android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());



            }
        });
```

Comment: are your overrding onBackPressed() in main activity?

Answer (score 2):

**Don't**

```
  System.exit(0);
  android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```

**Do**

```
Intent _intentOBJ= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    _intentOBJ.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    _intentOBJ.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    _intentOBJ.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(_intentOBJ);
```

Comment: @AndroidDeveloper I have rectified code.Try this way.

Comment: But it is re opening the app from where I exit. Not from starting. Why?

Comment: @AndroidDeveloper App close means `HIDE` from view. not delete

Comment: I want  that app will open from splash after exit

Comment: @AndroidDeveloper Its not possible AFAIK

Comment: but it is possible using  --  System.exit(0);
  android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());

Answer (score 1):

Try calling `ActivityCompat.finishAffinity(activity);` if your minSdk >= 16, this should close all the activities for your app

Answer (score 0):

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
alertDialog.setMessage(context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_close_dialog_msg));
alertDialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.app_close_dialog_msg_yes, new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {       
            switch (which) {
                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                    finish();
                    break;
             }
        }
```

This will do work.

Answer (score 0):

Do not add systems killprocess method instead you have to add `finishaffinity()` method to exit from application. Below is the code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
   alertDialog.setMessage(context.getResources().

getString(R.string.app_close_dialog_msg));
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.app_close_dialog_msg_yes,new

OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick (DialogInterface dialog,int which){
        dismiss();
        ((Activity) context).finishAffinity();

    }
});
```